# Query using internal field comparison with $where

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `people`.

I know that I can do this:

```
db.people.find( { $where: "this.lastname == this.firstname" } );
```

But how can I do something like this:

```
db.people.find( { $where: "this.lastname == Acquaintances.lastname" } );
```

Human translation: all the people that have at least one acquaintance with the same name.

Acquaintances is an array of subdocuments.

Comment: What's `Acquaintance`?  Local variable...another collection...field of `people`?

Comment: Acquaintance is an array of subdocuments.

Comment: You will need to loop `this.acquaintances` checking each row to see if `lastname == this.lastname`. Please note JS functions are notoriously slow and the implemented JS enigne (spider monkey) is single threaded. It is advised not to use JS functions at all.

Answer (score 0):

mongodb `$where` command is similar to `map reduce`, which process javascript expressions on the extracted data. It is only good for slow running background jobs. Dont use this at all in any normal circumstances.

```
function () {
    var arr = [];
    for (i in this.Acquaintances) {
        arr.push(this.Acquaintances[i].lastname);
    }
    return arr.indexOf(this.lastname) > -1;
}

db.people.find(f)
```

Check this [link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-%7B%7B%24where%7D%7DClausesandFunctionsinQueries) for more info abt `$where`

Comment: I understand the slow part, but what would be a better mongo structure for this task ?

Comment: @danip Probably a snapshotted iteration: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-{{snapshot%28%29}} of the entire result set